# Webpack production mode does not minify js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, minify

I created react app with by initializing webpack with `npm init -y` and then modified scripts and webpack config file manually. My file's contents are as below:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "arw.ecahangirov",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch ./frontend/src/index.js --output ./frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./frontend/src/index.js --output ./static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "weak-key": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.39.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        include: /\.js$/
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

Problem is that, when I run `npm run build`, webpack does not minify `main.js` file which is output. It results with `716kb` file size and by opening output file I observe that file is multilined and also contains comments. Why webpack does not care of minifiying in this case, although I started it with `--mode production`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a minifier for css.

Load this at top of your webpack config file

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
```

To the rules block:

```
rules: [
  //...
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [{loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},
      'css-loader',
      'postcss-loader',
      'sass-loader',
    ],
  },
  //...
]
```

To the optimization block:

```
optimization: { 
  minimizer: new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
}
```

To the plugins block:

```
plugins: [
  //...
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: [name].[hash].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css',
  }),
  //...
]
```

You will need to load that plugins first

```
npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin
npm install --save-dev optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
```

You can find a working config [here](https://github.com/xkmgt/Webpack-Boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

Comment: Note that this (1) **disables all default minimizers** (e.g. UglifyJS for JS/TS) and (2) **removes the sourceMap url**

Comment: For Webpack@5, prevent disabling other default minimizers by including `'...',` before your minimizer declaration per [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/)